# Installing a program to a mounted vhd, have installer use VHDs registry

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, installation, vhd

I am looking to install software (standard .exe not .msi) to a mounted offline VHD. If the installer is run on the mounted drive, the registry entries still go to my servers registry. Is there a way to mount the registry hive of the offline mounted VHD and have the installer insert registry entries there? I am aiming to do this all in PowerShell in the end as I have several to do, but I was just trying to figure out how to do it manually first so I can figure out how to do it in powershell. Any ideas?

Comment: You can mount a reg hive, but as far as I know not as `HKLM`/`HKCU` which will be where the `.exe` is looking for. If you know what registry settings are set, you could mount the reg hive and set them manually.

Comment: Unless the executable actually supports this kind of offline installation (which I doubt) you'd need to find out what the installer is actually doing, adjust the filesystem and registry paths, and re-implement the logic with the modified paths in PowerShell.